# twitter bootstrap: IE*8 error, not seen with chrome

Tags: internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the bootstrap form at https://github.com/jackilyn/bootstrap-contact/ into my site. after integration it works fine in chrome , but in IE8 , I am getting:

```
Couldn't load http://localhost/my_project/index.php/my_controller/assets/less/reset.less (404)
```

In IE8 , it appears that the CSS is not working. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include this file (reset.less) on your bootstrap.less file, then recompile less. The files with .less are meant to be compiled, and not served up by the browser.

If you are not compiling your own .less -- you maybe able to change that .less fill to a normal .css file.

Here is a link to the bootstrap.less file: 
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less

Comment: Hi Scott, you may have been planning to include a link, but it didn't work. Would you mind editing your answer? I want to upvote it! - Thank you in advance. Bill

Comment: Bill -- are you compiling your own .less files? Did you get this working? You can't serve .less files directly to a browser.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for looking at it. I checked the directory mentioned in the error message and reset.less is included, already. Perhaps I need to get the latest bootstrap less files since the original commit of https://github.com/jackilyn/bootstrap-contact/ was a year ago?

Comment: I guess I am confused where this is coming from:  http://localhost/my_project/index.php/my_controller/assets/less/reset.less

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that out. using chrome developer tools ( it is working in chrome ) , under the network tab I see that the directory for reset.less is http://localhost/my_project/assets/less/ not localhost/my_project/index.php/my_controller/assets/less/